# How can I emulate windows mouse behaviour in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, mouse

I've been using Windows for years and now I'm using Ubuntu's newest version (12.04.1) for desktop. Now this is all a matter of opinion, but is there a way to make the mouse pointer behave like on a Windows environment? Its slow and fancy attenuated movement sincerely angers me, it decreases my productivity and I can't find a way to behave the way I like it.

Please, does anyone know how to do this? Is there any system setting or plugin that fixes this issue?

Comment: Welcome to [SU], Aaron! Given that both Windows and Linux have highly-configurable mouse options, can you better describe what differences you're having issues with? I've found both to have nearly identical default settings in my own experience. Are you not happy about pointer speed? Double-click rate? Mouse trails? Acceleration?

Comment: @DarthAndroid, it's all about the speed, and the acceleration. I know these settings can be customized, but I just can't get it to behave as it does in Windows. It takes me a long time to get used to this kind of changes (I've been using the same keyboard and mouse for nearly 5 years and I don't plan on using any others until they stop working). So that's it. I want the mouse to go where I want it to fast, precisely, and without any fancy moves, just like Windows.

Comment: I would say start by turning Acceleration down or off, and then just play with mouse speed until you get it about the same. This will make the mouse feel more responsive while you try to match speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Darth Android with respect to the particular question, however just so there is some helpful information for future searches, there is a related answer on AskUbuntu that has several good general mouse tips.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/134323/cant-slow-down-the-pointer-speed-enough

I have found that in some cases of a particular mouse I had to go to xset to get the desired results, though most times the mouse preferences listed in the answer do the trick.

Comment: I can always try this if I switch to a more sensitive mouse. Appreciated.

Comment: Still, working with windows I can point to a position with almost my eyes closed. This is not the case with linux (or osx of course). Many people find no differences at all, but many others want to throw their computers from the window because of the bad mouse acceleration curve, that cannot be adjusted in the right way. There is a lot of information on the net, even apps that try to make thinks right, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, surprisingly enough the newest version of Ubuntu, unlike the few others i've tried, has a nicely moving mouse. Although I have set the settings on minimal it's good enough for me. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: This is a comment to the question, not an answer.  From Review

Comment: "This is a comment to the question, not an answer" Disagree, it's saying its fixed in the latest version.